# Magento 2.3.1 authorizenet-acceptjs does not support partial refunds

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.1, authorize.net, refund

After upgrading from 2.2.7 -> 2.3.1, we have successfully switched from deprecated authorize.net MD5 based hash direct post to SHA-512 signature key method.
The issue with new authorizenet module is now we'r not able to create partial refunds.
Looking and comparing with old module, I found *vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:68* has `protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = true;`
Question, what would be a proper way to extend new authorizenet module, to support partial refunds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default config option here vendor/magento/module-authorizenet-acceptjs/etc/config.xml

`<can_capture_partial>0</can_capture_partial>`

So it was done intentionally.

Comment: But order after completed it's not working of partial credit memo

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.3.4 was released today and the authorizenet-acceptjs module is deprecated in favor of the authorize.net module that was made by Authorize.net for Magento 2. It is available on the marketplace free of charge. I have not tested this yet but I assume it will fix the issue with partial refunds.

Comment: [M2.3.4 Release notes #platform-upgrades](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html#platform-upgrades). The core integration of the Authorize.net payment method has been deprecated. Please use the official payment integration that is available on Marketplace. Yep, that is what it says.